# Need clarification on how pointers work in the given piece of code

Tags: c, pointers

So here I have tiny piece of code

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    void *p = &a;
    int *ptr = p;
    printf("%u \n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

which produces result 10!

I am really confused why.

If we say that `*ptr = p`, then `*ptr` has address value of `p`.
While p points to address of a, and address of a contains 10.
I do not see how we get 10 from `*ptr`

Can someone explain?

Comment: `int *ptr = p;` What do you think this actually does, and what should be its purpose?!?

Comment: `int *ptr = p;` it's like saying `int *ptr;` `ptr = p;`

Answer (score 1):

`int *ptr = p` is declaring a pointer named `ptr` and setting the value of `ptr` equal to value of `p`. Both now contain the address of `a`. When they are dereferenced, they give the value stored in `a`.

A better way (imo) of writing that is `int* ptr = p;` This makes it more clear that `ptr` is a pointer and that you are declaring, not dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
int *ptr = p;
```

… is a declaration of variable `ptr`, with initialization.

The `=` in there is not an assignment operator, but part of the initialization syntax, and the `*` is not a dereferencing of `ptr`, but part of the type specification for `ptr`.

You can see that more easily by formatting the declaration this way:

```
int* ptr = p;
```

The original form reflects the fact that the C declaration syntax was designed to mimic the use of whatever you declare. With the declaration intentionally looking like the use, it's quite natural for a beginner to get confused. The syntax has been described as a failed experiment both by the original creators of C, and by the creator of C++.

---

To take more control of the C declaration syntax you can define

```
template< class T >
using type = T;
```

… and then declare e.g.

```
type<int*> ptr = p;
```

Or you can be more specific and name that type-builder, like

```
template< class T >
ptr_to = T*;
```

… and write

```
ptr_to<int> ptr = p;
```

---

Alternatives include using direct initialization syntax,

```
int* ptr( p );
```

… and curly braces uniform initialization syntax,

```
int* ptr{ p };
```

Comment: How is `int *ptr = p;` "a declaration of variable `p`"?

Answer (score 0):

Walking through your statements and logic:

> If we say that *ptr = p, then *ptr has address value of p.

This is correct.

> While p points to address of a,

This is correct.

> and address of a contains 10.

Actually, the variable 'a' has the value of 10 stored in it.

When you write:

```
printf("%u \n",*ptr);
```

The asterisk in front of 'ptr' is actually a unary operatior that is dereferencing the variable 'ptr'.  So what the code does is it goes to the address pointed to by ptr, then obtains that value of the pointer type at that address.  In this case, since it is a pointer defined by int*, an int is returned.  That value is 10.

See: 
[Dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)